# iOS : Saving from current UIImageView to Photo Album Failed - Unable to save to photo album

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to do an application that saving an image from the current main UIImageView when pressing a button  & save it to photo album.

What my program did was it shows an error after i press save to photo album button. Probably my code structure is not right. Or can someone show me the right code structure?

Here is my progress so far.

```
-(IBAction) saveToPhotoAlbum{

NSString *saveMyPhoto=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];

UIImage *saved=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:saveMyPhoto]; 

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)UIImagePNGRepresentation(saved)];
[imageData writeToFile:(NSString *)saved atomically:YES ];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saved, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);



- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    UIAlertView *alert;


    if (error)
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                           message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album." 
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    else 
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" 
                                           message:@"Image saved to Photo Album." 
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give a correct path to save the image. One that is also read and write, check out for Documents directory,  `NSString * docPath=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]`,then add you file name using the same method -stringByAppendingPathComponent: or just create a formatted string with both contents

Comment: Thank you Andrea. Firstly, I'll try to experiment your method. Secondly, i will consult again if any problem persist.